# error "undefined control sequence" after converting bibtex entries to \bibitem in Latex

Tags: latex, bibtex

I am using TEXnicCenter 2.0.2.
After compiling the .tex and .bibtex files, all citations are converted in bibitem in the .bbl file. I used the following bibitem in the .tex file:

```
\bibitem{nadel1990some}
B.~Nadel, \href{https://books.google.tn/books?id=f1evpwAACAAJ}{Some
applications of the constraint satisfaction problem}, no. n°~8 in CSC (Wayne
State University. Department of Computer Science), Wayne State University,
Department of Computer Science, 1990.
\newline\urlprefix\url{https://books.google.tn/books?id=f1evpwAACAAJ}
```

but I have this error in the first and the last line of the bibitem:

```
undefined control sequence
```

Can you help me please

Comment: You seem to be following the wrong approach with using BibTeX. Either way, if the error is as you claim, you should just add `\usepackage{hyperref}` as the last package in your preamble.